# second order ODE (equilibrium solutions)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given a second-order ODE $y''+5y=0$. Since it is autonomous, I am told to find its equilibrium solutions. I am also told to set $y$ as a constant $y_0$, so I get $0+5*y_0=0$ and y(t)=0. Why should we treat $y$ as a constant then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equilibrium state is where y does not change.

Thus $y=C$ is a constant and as you have mentioned, we have $y(t)=0$ which in this case is a stable ( not asymptotically stable) equilibrium point.

You may  change the problem to a system by  $$y=u_1, y'=u_2$$ which give you $$5u_1^2 +u_2^2=C$$  that is in phase plane your solutions are ellipses with the equilibrium point at the center.